# Java Select File in windows Explorer?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am working on a Java GUI, in which i have a JTable in which i have populated my file system, on JTable i have a Right Click Context Menu Like This

[image: My JTable GUI]

i right click on my File and it opens this folders in windows Explorer, to open a file/folder in windows explorer i am using this code

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    }
    try {
        desktop.open(myFile); //myFile is my Selected File
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

This opens myFile in windows Explorer Like this

[image: myimage]

i want that it should open windows and my file should be selected in windows explorer.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you think you know which [options](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853) to use? ;)

EDIT: whoops, it looks like you don't call explorer by executing it. Desktop class seems have no support for specifying options/parameters, so I guess this is not doable without using Process class.

Answer (score 2):

See this: [Open the windows explorer with a file selected in eclipse](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t77655.html)

[image]

If you want, for example, select the folder (let's say) C:\myFolder, just replace the arguments with:

```
/select,C:\myFolder
```